# How can I access inverted index in mysql

Tags: mysql, inverted-index

I am building some program that uses extensively inverted index. 
in sqlite3 via FTS engine I can access inverted index via 
fts4aux, like that(taken from fts4 tutorial)

```
##############
SELECT term, col, documents, occurrences FROM ft_terms
--     apple       |  *  |  1  |  1
--     apple       |  0  |  1  |  1
--     banana      |  *  |  2  |  2
--     banana      |  0  |  2  |  2
--     cherry      |  *  |  3  |  3
--     cherry      |  0  |  1  |  1
--     cherry      |  1  |  2  |  2
--     date        |  *  |  1  |  2
--     date        |  0  |  1  |  2
--     elderberry  |  *  |  1  |  2
--     elderberry  |  0  |  1  |  1
--     elderberry  |  1  |  1  |  1
--

###########
```

I really appreciate if anyone knows how to do the same with mysql engine. 
Thank you very much.